# Why is the text in this button not toggling back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll try and make it easier to help on this one.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button class="btn" id="follow-button"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Follow
  </button>
```

I want the button to change from saying "Follow" to "Following" when clicked. And when you click it while it says "Following" I want it to switch to "Follow".

How is this approached with JS?

Comment: What is `Toggle`? Not familiar with that plugin. Also, how many `.follow` elements are there? You probably want to use `$(this).html(txt)` inside the *click* handler to change the text of the clicked `.follow` element

Comment: In your codepen I do not see an object matching the `#extra-options` selector.

Answer (score 3):

There is no element on the page with the id extra-options. As a result,

`$("#extra-options").is(':visible')` always evaluates to false,  and

`$("#extra-options").Toggle();` always throws an  error.

EDIT: as @phil points out in the comments, the Jquery `toggle` function is spelled with a lower case t

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants to use jQuery's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Might want to point out that it's all lowercase, ie `.toggle()`, not `.Toggle()`

Comment: Okay, I pulled the code from a tutorial. How is this code operating? Would I have a separate button with the id #extra-options?

Comment: I guess I don't understand how it is working. Is this like an if statement? If it is visible, display this text. Otherwise? @Phil

Comment: Yes, to work there will need to be an element with the id 'extra-options'. And yes, the code is using a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is quite similar to an if/else